# Variance of parameters

Tags: variance, multivariate-analysis

I have three estimated parameters, $\hat{\beta_0}$,$\hat{\beta_1}$ and $\hat{\beta_2}$, these follow the ordering $\hat{\beta_1}\leq\hat{\beta_0}\leq\hat{\beta_1}$, where these parameters are estimates from a frequentist likelihood function. I know the variance of $\hat{\beta_1}$ and $\hat{\beta_2}$. Can the variance of $\beta_0$ be given in comparison to $\hat{\beta_1}$ and $\hat{\beta_2}$?. By in comparison, I mean like $var(\hat{\beta_1})\leq var(\hat{\beta_0}) \leq var(\hat{\beta_2})$.

Comment: Please edit this question so that the crucial information about the ordering makes sense and explain to us what it would mean for a variance to be "given in comparison".  Since this question seems to ask about whether order of random variables has any implications for order of variances, please first take a look at the closely related question at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108676/if-two-time-series-x-and-z-follow-0-leq-z-leq-x-can-we-say-that-text: perhaps it already has the answers you seek?

Comment: Also, it would be helpful to clarify whether instead of "parameters" we should read "estimators of parameters" (in a frequentist approach), or whether we are in a Bayesian framework.

Comment: (Making a couple of assumptions about what you meant to ask) -- on the information given here, I don't see any basis on which to conclude there's an ordering in the variances. If you really did mean to ask about the variances of the *estimates*, you can calculate them from the regression, or from the standard errors if you have those, or from the estimates and the t-ratios if you have those, or from the estimates, d.f. for error, and p-values if you have those.